# Is it possible to screenshot other opened window in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, screenshot

I have tried various of packages like screenshot-desktop, desktopCapturer and I managed to do a screenshot of my own desktop and the Electron app itself, but is it possible to make a screenshot of whats visible on the screen or for example screenshot of the VS code or are these applications blocking doing so?